# javascript - how to watch an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have a object and want to run a function if that object changes. I tried using angular `$watch`, but this only works without `setters`.

Searching for another solution i found `obj.observe` but `mdn` says it's obsolete and not widely supported. so is there any other way to run a function if my object changes?

**Edit:**

```
// watch using this doen't work, when update through ng-model 
 Object.defineProperties(self, {
        'myprop': {
            get: function () {return _myprop; },
            set: function (value) {
                _myprop = value;
            }
        },
```

Comment: Can we see the code you have tried so far?

Comment: what do you mean when you say `$watch` work only with `setters`? as long as you have anything in `scope` you can set a watch over it.

Comment: You can watch over anything as long as that value is changing in an angular context,

Comment: what do you mean when update through ng-bind, ng-bind binds from model to template. Were you meant to use ng-model instead?

Comment: @Wawy sorry i meant ng-model

Comment: Are you updating _myprop from outside angular context?

Comment: ng-model updates myprop which has a setter and sets _myprop - nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by $watch "working without setters" .

```
scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log('name has been changed: ' + $scope.name);
  scope.counter = scope.counter + 1;
});
```

Just start simple, put the above code into a controller and have a simple field modifying the $scope.name variable. You'll see in the console that the watch is triggered.